# making user methods for queue and encounterd this error

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, queue, java.util.scanner

I encountered this error for some reason while i'm making methods. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG5eU.png)

can someone please help me with this and here is the code i used

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Queue<Integer> q= new LinkedList<Integer>();
        NQ(q);
        displayQ(q);
        DQ(q);
        displayQ(q);}

    public static void NQ(Queue<Integer> q){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number of digits to be added: ");
        int digits= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter numbers to be Added:");
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
            q.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    public static void DQ(Queue<Integer> q){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number of digits to be remove: ");
        int digits= scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
            q.remove();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    public static void displayQ(Queue<Integer> q) {
        System.out.println(q);
    }}
```

This is the output of the code

```
Number of digits to be added: 5    
Enter numbers to be Added:  1  2  3 4  5  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
Number of digits to be remove: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
            at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
            at Test.DQ(Test.java:31)
            at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

What Should I Do?!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the way you are using `java.util.Scanner`.

Once you close a scanner, it also closes the input stream you passed it (`System.in` in this case). You can read more about this in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20Scanner%20is%20closed%2C%20it%20will%20close%20its%20input%20source%20if%20the%20source%20implements%20the%20Closeable%20interface.).

One way to get around this is to create a single Scanner instance and use that wherever you need to. In your sepcific case, you could do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Queue<Integer> q= new LinkedList<Integer>();
    NQ(q, scanner);
    displayQ(q);
    DQ(q, scanner);
    displayQ(q);

    scanner.close();
}
```

You would need update `NQ` and `DQ` to accept the scanner (instead of creating a new instance), and also not close the scanner in those methods.